# How do I calculate the cellular boundary map for $S^2$ with standard CW complex structure?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

I'm using Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, and he gives:

> [image]

---

Let's give $S^2$ the standard CW complex structure consisting of

- two $0$-cells: $\{e^0_1, e^0_2\}$,
- two $1$-cells: $\{e^1_E, e^1_W\}$,
- two $2$-cells: $\{e^2_N, e^2_S\}$.

---

I'm trying to compute $d_2$.

We have $d_2(e^2_N)=d_{NE}e^1_E + d_{NW}e^1_W$ where $d_{NE}$ is the degree of the map $S^1_N \to X^1 \to S^1_E$ and similarly for $d_{NW}$.

**However, I am not sure how to compute the degree of these maps. How is this done?**

Answer (score 1):

Fix an orientation of the two intervals so that the orientations are in opposite directions (think an arrow on the 1-cell). Now when we look at the maps used to compute the boundary, one will map $S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ via a map that has winding number 1. The other map will map $S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ via map that has winding number -1 (draw the quotient maps including the arrows). From here you can calculate the homology.

Comment: I ended up getting $d_2(e^2_N)=2e_E^1 + 2e_W^1$ since I think the composition $S^1_N \to X^1 \to S^1_E$ given in the definition gives us $z \mapsto z^2$ (thinking of $S^1 \subset \mathbb C)$. So, basically, I got $d_{NE}=2$ and $d_{NW}=2$. Do you get that too?

Comment: No, as I said in my comment, each map used to calculate the boundary has unital winding number. This follows from the fact that quotienting out by a contractible subcomplex is a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: If we take the attaching map of $e_N^2$ onto the $1$-skeleton: $S^1_N \to X^1$, then follow it with the map $X^1 \to X^1/(X^1-e^1_E) \cong S^1_E$, isn't this equivalent to taking $z \in S^1_N$ to $z^2 \in S^1_E$?

Comment: No, for example half of the circle gets sent to a single point.